# How to set a value to the components of a pointer structure

Tags: c

We need to allocate memory for a structure but i want to set a value to its components.

```
typedef struct val_s {
    int num_choice;
    int *choices;
} val_t;
```

the allocation with `int n=4`

```
val = malloc(n*sizeof(val_t));
if (val == NULL) {
    exit(1);
}

for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    val[i].choices = malloc(val[i].num_choice * sizeof(int));
    if (val[i].choices == NULL) {
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

Now if i want to set for example `num_choices=2 and *choices=[0,1]` How do i do that?

Comment: You're not initializing `val[i].num_choice` before you use it in `malloc()`.

Comment: To expound upon @0___________'s answer, you should look into [C99 compound literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/compound_literal).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't assign values to an array like that, so you need to do them one by one. If you have many of them, use a loop.

Example:

```c
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    const int num_choice = 2;

    val[i] = (val_t){num_choice, malloc(num_choice * sizeof(int))};

    // check that allocation succeeded before using the memory
    if (val[i].choices == NULL) {
        exit(1);
    }

    // assign the values:
    val[i].choices[0] = 0;
    val[i].choices[1] = 1;
}
```

Comment: what if num_choice > 2

Comment: @0___________ That's where the _"use a loop"_ comment comes in :-) Your way is of course very handy if there are a number of `int`s out of order.

Answer (score 2):

```
typedef struct val_s {
    size_t num_choice;
    int *choices;
} val_t;



val_t *allocateAndInit(const size_t n, const size_t numchoices, const int *initialArray)
{
    val_t *val = malloc(n*sizeof(*val));
    if(val)
    {
        for(size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            val[i].num_choice = numchoices;
            val[i].choices = malloc(numchoices * sizeof(val[i].choices[0]));
            if(val[i].choices) memcpy(val[i].choices, initialArray, numchoices * sizeof(val[i].choices[0]))
            else val[i].num_choice = 0;
        }
    }
    return val;
}

///example usage
int main(void)
{
    val_t *val = allocateAndInit(4,2, (int[]){1,2});
    /* .... */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want `num_choice` to be set to `2` for all objects of type `val_t` and you want the `choices` member of all objects to point to its own dynamically allocated array with the content `0` and `1`, then you can use the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct val_s {
    int num_choice;
    int *choices;
} val_t;

int main( void )
{
    val_t *val;
    int n = 4;

    //allocate memory for main array
    val = malloc( n * sizeof *val );
    if ( val == NULL )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "Memory allocation failure!\n" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    //allocate memory for sub-arrays and fill them from
    //template array
    for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        static const int template_array[] = { 0, 1 };

        val[i].num_choice = sizeof template_array / sizeof *template_array;
        val[i].choices = malloc( val[i].num_choice * sizeof(int) );
        if ( val[i].choices == NULL )
        {
            fprintf( stderr, "Memory allocation failure!\n" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }
        memcpy( val[i].choices, template_array, sizeof template_array );
    }

    //print content of val
    for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%d: %d |", i, val[i].num_choice );
        for ( int j = 0; j < val[i].num_choice; j++ )
        {
            printf( " %d", val[i].choices[j] );
        }
        printf( "\n" );
    }

    //cleanup
    for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        free( val[i].choices );
    }
    free( val );
}
```

This program has the following output:

```
0: 2 | 0 1
1: 2 | 0 1
2: 2 | 0 1
3: 2 | 0 1
```

As you can see, all `choices` arrays were correctly filled from the data in `template_array`.

I have designed the program in such a way that you can freely change the number of elements in `template_array` and it will automatically adapt the value of `num_choice` to match the new number of elements in the array.